# How to search and attach PDF file to email using java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am new to java and PDFBox.
I have split PDF using PDFBox and saved it in one target folder. The files name are like these -> D0000025667-T04292.pdf, D0000025668-T02119.pdf, D0000025670-T01125.pdf and so on.
I have connected to MS Access Database and table values are as shown below:

```
**Dealer Code        Email**
T04292            a@gmail.com
T04292            a@gmail.com
T02119            b@gmail.com
T01125            b@gmail.com
RS0009            c@gmail.com
RS0001            c@gmail.com
C01020            d@gmail.com
```

I know how to send mail with attachment in Java. My requirement is that I need to get Dealer Code from the table and search for PDF in the target with the help of Dealer Code.

Finally, I need to attach and send file to corresponding Email Id. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What have **you** done yet? What is the **problem** you ran into? Your question does sound like "I've been assigned a task. Do it for me!"

Comment: Its nt like tht. Using PDFBox I have already Splitted the PDF. but nw i need to search and attach that file with specific emails. But I hve tried for simple email function. I was strucked in searching and attaching the pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you really want, but I think this will help you:
This code visits all your files in the given path and filters the dealerName out of the filename. than you can go on with that (read the email for the dealer and send the mail)

```
    Path startPath = Paths.get("pathToYourDirectoryWithTheFiles");
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(startPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

                if (Files.isRegularFile(file)) {
                    String filename = file.getFileName().toString();

                    Pattern stringPattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*-(\\w*)\\.pdf");
                    Matcher matcher = stringPattern.matcher(filename);
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                        String dealer = matcher.group(1);

                        System.out.println(dealer);

                        // String mail = getMailForDealer(dealer);
                        // sendMailToDealer(mail,file);
                    }

                }

                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

you have to implement the methods `getMailForDealer(dealer)` and `sendMailToDealer(mail,file)` yourself.

in `getMailForDealer` you read the emailAdress for the given dealer (from the database or maybe you have read the data into a structure like `Map<String,String>`)

in `sendMailToDealer` you just attach the file to the mailAdress which you got from `getMailForDealer`

Comment: This Code works fine. Nw I am able to list all delaer Code. nw I need to attach the file to that email, which Dealer Code matches in a DB.. Hw can i achive this